# Manipulating variable type within LINQ expression

Tags: c#, sql, linq, lambda, notsupportedexception

I am trying to return a View of Age's that meet my selected Age filter. I read that LINQ cannot take actual C# operations, such as .ToString() or int.Parse, so you have to do them outside of the lambda expression itself.

I have tried that, but I am still getting a NotSupportedException, specifically

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Int32
>   CalculateAgeList(System.DateTime)' method, and this method cannot be
>   translated into a store expression.

I have tried debugging to figure out what is going on, but I cannot seem to fully find the issue's context.

My return statement is

```
else
{
    int tempvalue = int.Parse(ageValue);
    return View(actors.Where((bd => CalculateAge(bd.BirthDate) == tempvalue)));
}
```

And since `Actors.Age` is not mapped, I have to calculate Age from Birthdate, which is what `CalculateAge` does here:

```
private int CalculateAge(DateTime birthday)
{
    return ((int)(DateTime.Now - birthday).TotalDays / 365);
}
```

So I assumed that this should work since I removed all my conversions out of the expression, but it is still throwing a fit.

I also believe this "should" work as a similar process works when generating a list of Age's to initially filter through (populates the dropdown box of Age's that exist for filtering) as shown below

```
var AgeList = new List<string>();
var AgeListQry = (from d in db.Actors orderby d.BirthDate select d.BirthDate)
    .ToList();
AgeList.AddRange(AgeListQry.Select(bd => CalculateAgeString(CalculateAge(bd)))
    .Distinct());
ViewBag.ageValue = new SelectList(AgeList);
```

for a full picture it also converts to a string for that method since I cannot use .ToString() in the expression.

```
private string CalculateAgeString(int age)
{
    return age.ToString();
}
```

So why does it work for generating the list of ages, but not for the actual filtering process? Does it have to do with the uses of `Where` versus `Select` in my expressions?

Comment: You need to understand the difference between Linq to Objects and Linq to Entities. You are using Linq to Entites so any functions you want to write needs to work with `Expression`'s

Comment: You can work around this by calculating the range of birthdates that will result in the desired age, and using `actors.Where(a => a.BirthDate >= minBirthdate && a.BirthDate < maxBirthdate)`

Comment: It doesn't answer why (Scott does that), but you can also use the EntityFunctions.DiffYears function to carry out the conversion, which then allows Entity Framework to carry out the date subtraction using SQL functions.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.entityfunctions(v=vs.110).aspx  Scott is alluding to the fact that Entity Framework is taking the expression tree of functions and converting that into a SQL statement.  CLR code doesn't get executed inside the database system.

Comment: Okay, so here is my attempt of understanding what you are all saying (thank you as well for the responses!). In the instance where this does work, I am doing it on an Object of strings- AgeList, right? Whereas what I am trying to do now, is use it on an "entity" which I am not sure if you mean a variable/field (like Birthday/Age) or actors itself? I am still trying to keep all the terminology straight in my head. And I am not sure how to use this DiffYears function, will it be in the expression, or in a method call? Thank you!

Comment: Figured it out, I didn't realize that .Where turns it all into direct SQL, so I just calculated the problem ahead of time, as phoog said, int tempvalue = int.Parse(ageValue);
                DateTime calculatedAge = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1*tempvalue);
                var test = actors.Where((bd => bd.BirthDate < calculatedAge)).ToArray();
                return View(test);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to execute the finding of Age outside of the `.Where` (which turns its code into SQL syntax)

```
 {
 int tempvalue = int.Parse(ageValue);
 DateTime calculatedAge = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1*tempvalue);
 var test = actors.Where((bd => bd.BirthDate < calculatedAge)).ToArray();
 return View(test);
 }
```